# How to force a WPF control or its bindings to load before it's visible

Tags: wpf, xaml

For efficiency, it appears WPF only loads visual elements when necessary.  But what if you need them to load when their parent loads?

For example, I have a split-button control with a drop-down `CheckListBox`.  Each `CheckListBox` item is bound to an `IsSelected` property and a `Select` command.  Changing `IsSelected` in the ViewModel has the same effect as clicking a row in the control, but only once the drop-down portion of the control is loaded.  Before that the select command doesn't react to changes in the `IsSelected` property (presumably) because the binding and command don't yet exist.  Is there a clean way to force the split-button's contents to load at the same time it's parent loads, or otherwise connect it's bindings at initialization rather than when first entering the visual tree?